# Method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::find does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications

Hi currently trying to link to a page that describes all details about an event from a page that has the list of events. When a user clicks on specific event on the event page, it will link to another page of the event's description.

I did learn a few ways from other questions on stackoverflow, but I dont have the clue what is going on with the error

Here are some of the code details

My Route file

```
//route to see the page to all events
Route::get('/event', [EventController::class, 'index']);

//route for individual events
Route::get('/event/{id}', function ($id) {

    $myEvent = Event::find($id);

    return view('event-desc', ['events' => $myEvent]);

});
```

event-desc is the page for a certain event's description

Here is the event.blade.php (all events) short sum up

```
@foreach($events as $event)

  <li><a href="{{URL::to('/event/' . $event->id)}}"></li> 
  <p>{{$event->event_name}}</p>

@endforeach
```

and also what about the event-desc.blade.php (the event description page) ? how should i start and display the specific clicked event and display the data that is only to that specific event?

pretty new in laravel, perhaps a link to a video regarding this would be okay!

Comment: `Event` is the event dispatcher alias ... I am assuming you created a Model named Event? if that is the case you would have to reference that class, not `Event` in the root namespace

Comment: So how should I differentiate it at the `$myEvent = Event::find($id);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing the path to the model, which in most cases would look like

```
use App\Models\Event;
```

You should put it below

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually have found a new way to do this. Thank you for your help though! keep it up!